# Ellipse type in PCA example

Tags: r, probability, ellipse, confidence-interval

In [this example](https://www.r-bloggers.com/computing-and-visualizing-pca-in-r/), the author uses ggbiplot to visualise PCA of iris data. he also draws ellipses around the groups. My question - what type of ellipses are those (probability ellipse, confidence ellipse, etc..)? And what do they represent ?

The original:

[image]

I have extracted one group from the iris dataset (setosa).

```
log.ir <- log(iris[1:49, 1:4]) # only setosa
ir.species <- iris[1:49, 5]
```

Plotted it using the same *ggbiplot* function (Im using the red ellipse as "how-it-should-look-like" with other libraries. Note: that ggbiplot default ellipse.prob probability defaults to **68%**) :

**Code**:

```
library(ggbiplot)
g <- ggbiplot(ir.pca, obs.scale = 1, var.scale = 1, 
              groups = ir.species, ellipse = TRUE, 
              circle = TRUE)
g <- g + scale_color_discrete(name = '')
g <- g + theme(legend.direction = 'horizontal', 
               legend.position = 'top')
print(g)
```

**Result**:

[image]

Tried using *[stat_ellipse](http://ropensci.github.io/plotly/ggplot2/stat_ellipse.html)* :

**Code**:

```
log.ir <- log(iris[1:49, 1:4]) # only setosa

ir.species <- iris[1:49, 5]

# apply PCA - scale. = TRUE is highly 
# advisable, but default is FALSE. 
ir.pca <- prcomp(log.ir,
                 center = TRUE,
                 scale. = TRUE)

pca1_x <- ir.pca$x[, 1]

pca2_y <- ir.pca$x[, 2]

# create data
set.seed(101)
n <- 1000
x <- rnorm(pca1_x, mean = 2)
y <- rnorm(pca2_y, mean = 2)
df <- data.frame(x = x, y = y, group = "A")

qplot(data = df, x = x, y = y) + stat_ellipse(level = 0.68)
```

**Result**:

[image]

And [Momocs](http://vbonhomme.github.io/Momocsdoc/conf_ell.html) :

**Code**:

```
log.ir <- log(iris[1:49, 1:4]) # only setosa
ir.species <- iris[1:49, 5]

pca1_x <- ir.pca$x[, 1]
pca2_y <- ir.pca$x[, 2]

plot(pca1_x, pca2_y, asp = 1)

library(Momocs)
ce068 <- conf_ell(pca1_x, pca2_y, conf = 0.68)
cols <- col_hot(10)

lines(ce068$ell, col = cols[9])
```

**Result**:

[image]

In all cases I used 68% like the ggbiplot uses, but in all cases I have a different ellipse. What am I missing here ?

Comment: Good effort, do you mind adding code for each plot?

Comment: @zx8754 updated with code, hope that helps. Do you know what the ellipses are in the original example ?

Comment: Note that this question is really about data ellipses, and not about PCA as far as I can tell.

Comment: @Axeman Agreed, but since im plotting a PCA and ellipses are part of it (and because Im trying to figure out ellipses type in this PCA ) I mentioned it as another clue that might help lead me to an answer